# element => command in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I see a code as below in https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-efs/blob/master/examples/complete/main.tf#L58

```
  # Mount targets / security group
  mount_targets = { for k, v in toset(range(length(local.azs))) :
    element(local.azs, k) => { subnet_id = element(module.vpc.private_subnets, k) }
  }
```

I am trying to understand what => means here. Also this command with for loop, element and =>.
Could anyone explain here please?

Comment: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the `=>` symbol isn't an independent language feature but is instead just one part of the [`for` expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) syntax when the result will be a mapping.

A `for` expression which produces a sequence (a tuple, to be specific) has the following general shape:

```
[
  for KEY_SYMBOL, VALUE_SYMBOL in SOURCE_COLLECTION : RESULT
  if CONDITION
]
```

(The `KEY_SYMBOL,`  portion and the `if CONDITION` portion are both optional.)

The result is a sequence of values that resulted from evaluating `RESULT` (an expression) for each element of `SOURCE_COLLECTION` for which `CONDITION` (another expression) evaluated to `true`.

When the result is a sequence we only need to specify one result expression, but when the result is a mapping (specifically an object) we need to specify both the keys *and* the values, and so the mapping form has that additional portion including the `=>` symbol you're asking about:

```
{
  for KEY_SYMBOL, VALUE_SYMBOL in SOURCE_COLLECTION : KEY_RESULT => VALUE_RESULT
  if CONDITION
}
```

The principle is the same here except that for each source element Terraform will evaluate both `KEY_RESULT` *and* `VALUE_RESULT` in order to produce a key/value pair to insert into the resulting mapping.

The `=>` marker here is just some punctuation so that Terraform can unambiguously recognize where the `KEY_RESULT` ends and where the `VALUE_RESULT` begins. It has no special meaning aside from being a delimiter inside a mapping-result `for` expression. You could think of it as serving a similar purpose as the comma between `KEY_SYMBOL` and `VALUE_SYMBOL`; it has no meaning of its own, and is only there to mark the boundary between two clauses of the overall expression.

When I read a `for` expression out loud, I typically pronounce `=>` as "maps to". So with my example above, I might pronounce it as "for each *key* and *value* in source collection, *key result* maps to *value result* if the condition is true".

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expressions use the operator symbol =, which reads as "goes to." Input parameters are specified on the operator's left side, and statement/expressions are specified on the right. Generally, lambda expressions are not directly used in query syntax but are often used in method calls. Query expressions may contain method calls.

Lambda expression syntax features are as follows:

- It is a function without a name.
- There are no modifiers, such as overloads and overrides.
- The body of the function should contain an expression, rather than a statement.
- May contain a call to a function procedure but cannot contain a call to a subprocedure.
- The return statement does not exist.
- The value returned by the function is only the value of the expression contained in the function body.
- The End function statement does not exist.
- The parameters must have specified data types or be inferred.
- Does not allow generic parameters.
- Does not allow optional and ParamArray parameters.
- Lambda expressions provide shorthand for the compiler, allowing it to emit methods assigned to delegates.

The compiler performs automatic type inference on the lambda arguments, which is a key advantage.